# How to fetch hierarchy data with dynamic changes

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have emp table like as follows:

```
Empname              Mgr_hierarchy            
-------    ---------------------------------
arjun      Giri    | Raj    | Suresh
arun       arjun   | Giri   | Raj    | Suresh
alex       Pandey  | Ravi   | Suresh
adam       alex    | Pandey | Ravi   | Suresh
bux        alex    | Pandey | Ravi   | Suresh
bony       Agarwal | Ram    | Nitesh | Suresh
```

A manager table as like follows:

```
Mgr_names
----------
Raj
Ram
Ravi
```

I want to fetch the all the employee details who are have the listed managers in their hierarchy,

I have use the following code for that

```
    select empname from `project.dataset.emp`
 where 
(mgr_hierarchy like '%Raj%' or mgr_hierarchy like '%Ravi%' or mgr_hierarchy like '%Ram%')
```

But the problem is the manager table is dynamically changing; as of now it contains 3 values after one month these managers are replaced with another 3 or 4 values. So every time I am changing the condition. Are there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split()` and `unnest()`:

```
select e.*
from emp e cross join
     (unnest(split(e.Mgr_hierarchy, ' | '))) as mgr join
     manager m
     on m.mgr_name = mgr;
```

I would recommend that you fix your data structure.  Encoding hierarchies as fixed strings is quite painful.  At the very least you could be using arrays.

Comment: Can we use list of values in like operator

Comment: @kalyan4uonly . . . Why would you want to do that if you are looking for all values that are already stored in a table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use in operator as:

```
select empname from `project.dataset.emp`
 where 
(mgr_hierarchy in (select names from Mgr_names where names like '%your search query%'  ) )
enter code here
```

You can search now any names and that will get all belonging from table Mgr_names and for those member empname will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Like Nikesh answered, using the `IN` clause with a subquery would do the work:

```
SELECT empname FROM `project.dataset.emp`
WHERE (mgr_hierarchy IN
  (SELECT names FROM Mgr_names))
```

I made a new answer, since the LIKE clause was not needed.